# Url.Action doesnt go back to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I cant find why my Url.Action doesnt go back in controller.

This is my controller HomeController

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var list = await db.News.ToListAsync();
            list.Reverse();
            list.Take(5);
            return View(list);
        }

        public FileContentResult GetImage(int imageId)
        {
            Image image = db.Images.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == imageId);

            if (image != null)
            {
                return File(image.ImageData, image.ImageType);
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
```

This is my Index view

```
<div class="main_page_main_content_body">
                <div class="main_page_main_content_body_image">
                    <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "HomeController", new { imageId = Model.ElementAt(0).ImageId })" />
                </div>
                <div class="main_page_main_content_body_title">
                    @Model.ElementAt(0).NewsTitle
                </div>
                <div class="main_page_main_content_body_text">
                    @Model.ElementAt(0).ShortNewsDescription
                </div>
</div>
```

Then i try to debug it does not go back to the controller, just goes through.

I think it has something to do with the out of sync routes. Explain someone what the problem is, please :c

Comment: maybe Model.ElementAt(0) is null...

Comment: Hi @Afester, the url should be: `@Url.Action("GetImage", "Home",xxx)` not `HomeController`.